# What are the different subgroups of $A_4 \times \mathbb Z_2$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Is there a place where I can find the subgroups of $A_4 \times \mathbb Z_2$ or is there a way I can list them completely? In particular, given the set of elements in terms of the generators, i.e.,
$\langle a,x \mid a^3 = x^2 = (ax)^3 = e \rangle$, that generates $A_4$
and $\langle b \mid b^2 = e \rangle $ that generates $\mathbb Z_2$, I would like to find all the possible ways to get the different subgroups.

For example, subgroup $\mathbb Z_2 = \{e,x\}, \{e,b \}, \{e, a x a^2 \}, \ldots$ .

I am a physicist so I apologize if I have phrased this incorrectly.

Comment: If $H$ is a subgroup, then it's natural projection into $A_4$ or into $\mathbb{Z}_2$ must also be a subgroup. So we can look for subgroups by checking that their projections are subgroups. Conversely, we can take subgroups and construct subgroups but you have to make sure you get all of them (there is an example of when we might miss one with the group $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$).

Answer (score 0):

I'll describe a classification of subgroups of $G\times \Bbb Z_2$ for any finite group $G$. This leaves you the task of understanding why the classification is true and then implementing it for $G=A_4$. But I think the more general version is more illuminating and will lead to better understanding down the road.

So let $H$ be a subgroup of $G\times \Bbb Z_2$. Define $G_0 = \{(g,0)\colon g\in G\}$, which is isomorphic to $G$ itself. Since the intersection of two subgroups is again a subgroup, we know that $H_0 = H\cap G_0$ is a subgroup of $G_0$, hence is isomorphic to a subgroup of $G$ (and we'll abuse notation and call $H_0$ a subgroup of $G$). Moreover, since $[G\times \Bbb Z_2:G_0] = 2$, we have $[H:H_0] \mid 2$ and so $[H:H_0]$ equals either $1$ or $2$.

The case $[H:H_0]=1$ (equivalently, $H\subseteq G_0$) is easy: there's one such example for each subgroup of $G$.

The case $[H:H_0]=2$ has two flavors. Let $H_1 = H \setminus H_0$, and let $\bar H_j$ ($i=0,1$) be the projection of $H_j$ onto $G$ (that is, forget the second coordinates). Then choose any $x\in \bar H_1$; then $(x,1)^{-1}H_1 = H_0$, and so $H = H_0 \times \langle(x,1)\rangle$. (This includes the case $x=e$, when $H = \bar H_0 \times \langle(e,1)\rangle = \bar H_0 \times \Bbb Z_2$.)

Comment: I don't think your last sentence works, see for instance the group $H$ in $A_4\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ generated by the element $((1,2,3,4),1)$. Then we get that $H_0=\langle (1,3)(2,4)\rangle$ hence we get a cyclic group isomorphic to a non-trivial direct product. The point is that $(x,1)$ in your last sentence may not be of order two. To do this kind of thing properly you might need Goursat's lemma.

Comment: Aha, yes you're right that "direct product" isn't correct. Is it still right to say that $H$ is generated by $H_0$ and $(x,1)$ and that $H_0$ has index $2$ in $H$? - I've made the answer community wiki to encourage improvements and corrections.